# The background image intended for the header is displayed as a background image on the entire page

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am in the process of expanding my website and wanted to have an automatic slideshow in the header. 
As a basis I used the tutorial from this website: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/01/02/fullscreen-background-image-slideshow-with-css3/

However, the problem is that the background image is not only displayed in the header, but on the whole page.

The question now is what I have to change so that the "cb-slideshow" element doesn't cover the whole website, but only the header.

Since I am still quite a beginner in the whole CSS area, I only tried to change the position to relative at the ".cb-slideshow li span", which of course didn't work.

```html
<section id="home" class="tt-fullHeight" data-stellar-vertical-offset="50" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.2">

    <ul class="cb-slideshow">
        <li><span>Image 01</span><div><h3>JavaScript</h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 02</span><div><h3>NGC-3432</h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 03</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 04</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 05</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
        <li><span>Image 06</span><div><h3></h3></div></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="intro ">
        <div class="intro-sub">Ich bin NAME</div>
        <h1>TEXT</h1>
        <p>TEXT</p>

        <div class="social-icons">
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li><a href="TWITTER"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <!-- I have removed the remaining icons for the clarity times -->
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- /.social-icons -->
    </div>

    <div class="mouse-icon">
        <div class="wheel"></div>
    </div>

</section>
```

```css
.cb-slideshow,
.cb-slideshow:after {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 0;
}
.cb-slideshow:after {
    content: '';
    /*background: transparent url(../../beta/assets/JS-captcha.jpg) repeat top left;*/
}
.cb-slideshow li span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    color: transparent;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: none;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 0;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: imageAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -moz-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -o-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    -ms-animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
    animation: titleAnimation 36s linear infinite 0s;
}
.cb-slideshow li div h3 {
    font-family: 'BebasNeueRegular', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240px;
    padding: 0;
    line-height: 200px;
    display:none;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(1) span {
    background-image: url(../../beta/assets/JS-captcha.jpg);
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) span {
    background-image: url(../../beta/assets/NGC-3432.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) span {
    background-image: url(/beta/assets/JS-captcha.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) span {
    background-image: url(/beta/assets/JS-captcha.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) span {
    background-image: url(/beta/assets/JS-captcha.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) span {
    background-image: url(/beta/assets/JS-captcha.jpg);
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(2) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 6s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 6s;
    -o-animation-delay: 6s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 6s;
    animation-delay: 6s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(3) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 12s;
    -o-animation-delay: 12s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 12s;
    animation-delay: 12s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(4) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 18s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 18s;
    -o-animation-delay: 18s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 18s;
    animation-delay: 18s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(5) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 24s;
    -o-animation-delay: 24s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 24s;
    animation-delay: 24s;
}
.cb-slideshow li:nth-child(6) div {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 30s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 30s;
    -o-animation-delay: 30s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 30s;
    animation-delay: 30s;
}
/* Animation for the slideshow images */
@-webkit-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
        -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
        -o-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
        -ms-animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes imageAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0;
        animation-timing-function: ease-in; }
    8% { opacity: 1;
        animation-timing-function: ease-out; }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    25% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Animation for the title */
@-webkit-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-moz-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-o-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@-ms-keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
@keyframes titleAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    8% { opacity: 1 }
    17% { opacity: 1 }
    19% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 0 }
}
/* Show at least something when animations not supported */
.no-cssanimations .cb-slideshow li span{
    opacity: 1;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1140px) {
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 140px }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .cb-slideshow li div h3 { font-size: 80px }
}
```

It was expected that the background would only be displayed and updated in the header. Currently, however, the background images are displayed across the entire Web site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have now managed it by completely removing the "position: absolute;", thank you very much for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

.classofthebackground{
width:100%; /if necessary based on the resolution of the image/
background-size: cover;
}

and also dont forget to use right position for the particular class

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "overflow: hidden;" to your .cb-slideshow class.

Also, you've set a height and width of 100% so that will default to the browser width and height. Try reducing that size also.

Answer (score 0):

The position relative attribute wont work, because it is relative to what?You should have another object that has the attribute of absolute.
There are 2 ways to do it:
1.You create a wrapper class around the slideshow, set the position to relative and the .cbslideshow to absolute regarding the wrapper class.This method is good if you have multiple images to show.
2.You set the .classofthebackground to width: 100% which will cover the header.Fast for a small amount of images.

Just a tip, don't use plain html and css with that.WAY too much work.Use bootstrap.You dont have to use css.Everything is premade for you to copy-paste and modify.

Good luck.